# Capture the number of 'paths' an ID takes

Tags: sas

I have a data set that captures a persons 'route' by listing the nodes. The data looks like this:

```
data have;
    input id node $;
    datalines;
    1 A 
    1 B 
    1 C 
    2 B 
    2 C 
    3 A 
    3 C 
    4 A 
    4 B 
    4 C 
; 
run;
```

I am trying to capture all different routes the IDs have taken, and then count the number of times that appears. Example output:

```
Route  Count
ABC      2
BC       1
AC       1
```

Is the only way to achieve this with a transpose statement to measure stop 1,2,3,etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easiest to just build up a string for each "path".

```
data want;
  do until(last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    length route $30 ;
    route=cats(route,node);
  end;
  drop node;
run;
proc freq ;
   tables route;
run;
```

If the nodes are more complex than single letters then you might want to use CATX() instead to insert a delimiter between them in the generated ROUTE string. That would avoid potential confusion when the concatenated nodes looked like another node.  For example if there was a node 'AB' it would look the same as node 'A' followed by node 'B'.